# Why does it print "undefined" on the console?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

I have the following JavaScript code:

please help

```
let statement = ['Kim is a good, kind and smart boy'];
    
let kim = {
  message () {
    console.log(statement);
  },
  interest () {
    console.log('sports');
  }
}
console.log(kim.message());
console.log(kim.interest());
```

I expect that it should print this output:

```
[ 'Kim is a good, kind and smart boy' ]
sports
```

But instead, it prints the following:

```
[ 'Kim is a good, kind and smart boy' ]
undefined
sports
undefined
```

Why does it print "undefined" after each function within the method?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, what are you printing? Or are you just calling `kim.message` and `kim.interest`?

Comment: Yes, I'm just calling those functions out.

Comment: Can you show how? Because if you are console logging them, then that's your issue.

Comment: Those functions aren't returning anything so you automatically get `undefined` as the result of calling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're calling `console.log(kim.message());` and `console.log(kim.interest());`

console.log prints the return value of the passed function but because both the function don't have a return statement console.log prints `undefined` that's way you see those additional `undefined` logs.

Comment: Ahhh! I see. Thanks for the help. I have changed console.log(kim.message()); and console.log(kim.interest()); to kim.message(); and kim.interest();

Now i'm getting the right output without undefined